# \hyphenation does not work

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

TeX trys to hypehnate my word "universeller" in a totally wrong way. It makes it to "Üniverseller" and removes the quotation marks in the front before.

When I use `\mbox` it writes the word over the margin break point and if i write the word in `\hyphenation{universeller}` it doesn't even show the word. Any idea why?`\hyphenation{uni-ver-sel-ler}` also doesnt work

If I write it normally Tex makes the two words `"Fabian" universeller` to `Fabianüni-`:

[image]

Comment: Are you loading `babel`? How about giving us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `"` for the quotes, but rather `\`\`` and `''` (opening and closing). Consult the documentation of German `babel` for more about quotes.

Comment: Or even better, use the wonderful [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package and its `\enquote{foo}` command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. I already used babel german and csquotes but didn't knew the \enquote command. with \enquote it works perfect without \mbox or \hypehnation. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you load the `babel` package with the `[ngerman]` option -- I'm taking a wild guess here that your document's language is German... -- LaTeX should have no problem hyphenating the word "universeller". See the MWE (minimum working example) below, which uses the LuaLaTeX format just to be able to use the nifty [showhyphens](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/showhyphens) package to indicate all hyphenation points with thin red vertical bars.

For sure do not place the word `universeller` into an `\mbox` unless you want to *disable* hyphenation. And don't provide the instruction `\hyphenation{universeller}` unless you, again, want to disable its hyphenation.

Furthermore, don't write `"universeller"` since with the `ngerman` option set, `babel` will interpret `"u` as a shortcut command for `\"{u}` and therefore typeset `ü` rather than `"u`. For the automatic use of language-appropriate quotation marks, do consider using the `csquote` package and its `\enquote` command, i.e., start writing `\enquote{universeller}`. (As @Dan has pointed out in a comment, the `babel` shortcut `"` gobbles up space after it. This explains why it's necessary to write `...seller" \ ---` in the MWE to get a space between the end of the word and the em-dash. It also explains what you get the decidedly incorrect `”Fabianüniverseller`...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{showhyphens,csquotes,babel}
\begin{document}
universeller

"universeller" \ --- This is a mistake!

``universeller'' --- U.S.-style quotation marks

\enquote{universeller} --- German-style quotation marks
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer came just before I completed mine. I would only add the observation that macros ignore spaces when looking for arguments. That is why the space in the supplied code: `"Fabian" universeller` disappears.

Comment: @Dan -- Thanks for this. I've incorporated you comment about `"` gobbling trailing whitespace into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer shows how to get the output you need so I'll just answer your question about `\hyphenation`

An instruction such as

```
\hyphenation{uni-ver-sel-ler}
```

Never typesets anything, it is a declaration (normally in the document preamble) that tells TeX how to hyphenate that word, so that when you use `universeller` in the document hyphenation and line breaks are allowed at the indicated places. However you should not need that as (if typesetting German) they are in fact the default hyphenation positions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\showhyphens{universeller}

\selectlanguage{english}

\showhyphens{universeller}

\end{document}
```

Produces log lines showing how this word is hyphenated in German:

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 uni-ver-sel-ler
```

and in English:

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 uni-verseller
```

If you add

```
\hyphenation{universeller}
```

as shown here

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\hyphenation{universeller}
\showhyphens{universeller}

\selectlanguage{english}
\hyphenation{universeller}
\showhyphens{universeller}

\end{document}
```

Then the log shows

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 universeller


[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 universeller
```

Showing how the hypheation has now been disabled for the word in German and English.